# Same column size for multiple tables

Tags: html, xslt, html-table, column-width

I need to have the same size for the header column and the table inside the body. It is not possible to add a fixed value, because the amount of columns can depend (creating a xslt to convert a xml to html)

This is a small example to make my point:

```
    <html>
     <table border="2px">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Firstname</td>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <table border="2px">
        <tr>
         <td>Vertongen</td>
         <td>Marc</td>
        </tr>
       </table>        
      </tbody>
    </table> 
   </html>
```

Expected result:

```
Name     |Firstname|
Vertongen|Marc     |
```

Actual result:

```
Name|Firstname|
Vertongen|Marc|
```

Comment: So why do you have a `table` nested in the `tbody`? If you simply have the `tr` elements in there then the columns should be fine.

Comment: This is actually to solve another problem. Page breaks :) ...
We have to be able to keep the second table together, without seperating rows. This is just a simple representation of what we are trying to accomplish!

Comment: @Kenny I edited the answer once again, hope this help.Check this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS FluidColumn, you said you can't use fixed widths because you want to expand to more columns, so i added extra columns,

```css
 
   table {
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
 min-width: 500px;
border: 1px solid #333;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
 <table border="2px">
      <thead>
       <tr class="ha">
        <td>Name Name Name Name Name</td>
        <td>Firstname</td>
         <td>Name1</td>
        <td>Firstname1</td>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <table border="2px">
        <tr >
         <td>Vertongen</td>
         <td>Marc</td>
         <td>Vertongen1</td>
         <td>Marc1</td>
        </tr>
        
       
         </table>      
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

**EDIT**

Now you can add what ever length,but when you expand the table, you can view the hidden content too.Which means that if a text in a column is lager then the width, it never overwrites the other column.

Working [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/fb5j8q2e/1/)

**EDIT 1**

You can use "vw". What you have to do is just add `font-size: 10px; font-size: 2.5vw;` in to your table css. They're the units associated with setting the viewport width.

Working [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/eauthv3u/)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but as stated, we can't use fixed widths.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. The problem we have now is that, if a text in a column is lager then the width, it overwrites the other column.

Comment: @Kenny I edited the answer once again, hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works :)
I just need one more thing, if we have allot of columns, the size of the font should scale. Is it possible to do this dynamically, or do we need to implement some kind of logic for this?

Comment: @Kenny you meant change the font size dynamically..you can use " vw". What you have to do is just add `font-size: 10px;`
    `font-size: 2.5vw;` in to your table css. They're the units associated with setting the viewport width.  Working fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/eauthv3u/

Comment: @Kenny I hope that helped. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the answer, but i doesn't seem te be working in jsfiddle? When i'm adding multiple columns, the font isn't changing?

Comment: @Kenny No it's changing, because those two CSS attributes applied to your whole table, which means it has to have act whether there are 2 column or even more. See i added another column.https://jsfiddle.net/eauthv3u/2/ .It's working on JSFiddle.What's your browser?"vw" works in IE 10+, Firefox 19+, Chrome 34+, Safari 7+, Android 4.4+, iOS 6+ and

Chrome 20-34, Safari 6 - Supported but has repaint issue

Answer (score 0):

I have edited Kenny's answer:

```
 <table border="2px">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Firstname</td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <table border="2px">
    <tr>
     <td>Vertongen</td>
     <td>Marc</td>
    </tr>
   </table>        
  </tbody>
</table>
<style>
table {
table-layout: fixed;
}   
</style>
```